# Text() is ignoring multiple paragraphs from AttributedString(markdown: ...)

Tags: swiftui, markdown, attributedstring

Given the markdown string "**Line 1**\n\nLine 2" I expect an output of

**Line 1**

Line 2

Instead I get

**Line 1**Line 2

Surely this isn't a limitation of markdown or AttributedString. What am I missing?! How do I specify multiple paragraphs if not with two blank lines?

```
struct DemoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: "**Line 1**\n\nLine 2"))
    }
}
```

Comment: It works as expected if you use the markdown string directly: `Text("**Line 1**\n\nLine 2")`

Comment: Curious. This appears to be a feature (?!) of string literals and Text(). Doesn't get parsed if you place it into a string variable first. In either event it does not do a full parsing of the string. So, my problem remains... but thanks for the look.

Comment: @Rumbles Have you been able to render both headings and newlines? It seems the hardest of the jobs, what should be a simple thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discovered via the [Apple Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682957), `.inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace` is needed:

```
Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: "**Line 1**\n\nLine 2", 
                           options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(interpretedSyntax: 
                                                       .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace)))
```

And, of course, for those that may come along this answer later, it's worth mentioning that if you don't need to use `AttributedString` directly or aren't passing a variable to `Text`, you can use the string literal with markdown directly:

```
Text("**Line 1**\n\nLine 2")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It does "work" insofar as it allows single newlines to act as paragraph separators. However, I must be missing some thing big about the user of markdown... the only syntax that appears supported is bold and italic. Headings, etc do not appear to be parsed at all?!

Comment: Could be. I’d need to experiment more with the available options. If this answers the original question, though, please consider accepting and or upvoting.

Comment: It so hard to do such simple thing :(

Comment: This *seems* to disregard blockquote markdown syntax: character ">".  When I add this attribute it does the the double-asterisk emphasizing of text as expected, but treats ">" like it's "\>". But without this option, though the white space in the original text is disappears, so do the ">" characters, which means it seems to recognize that ">" is markdown.

Answer (score -2):

Ok it is how it works

```
Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: "**Line 1**\nLine 2", options: .init(interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace)))
```

But if you load text from plist it doesn't work with placing there \n What you need to do is add Enter + Option